# new Date() Operating System Dependent?

Tags: javascript, regex, timezone

Alright so I'm using javascript to return the shorthand timezone of the users system time with a simple regex like so

```
new RegExp('\\(.*\\)').exec(new Date().toString())[0];
```

this works great under Mac using chrome for example i get (UTC) or (EDT) or (PDT) as expected however this functionality falls on its face once we get over to windows using chrome as well,

so `new Date().toString()` on mac returns

> Tue Apr 08 2014 16:07:09 GMT-0400 (EDT)

while `new Date().toString()` on windows returns

> Tue Apr 08 2014 16:08:11 GMT-0400 (US Eastern Daylight Time)

This doesn't make any sense to me, why would something like this be operating system dependent, was there a change in v8 that has caused this bug recently, my goal is to have a simple short return of the shorthand property of the user timezone in Chrome, but this is the issue im facing and I'm pretty confused on why, if anyone has a solution or maybe an idea to force the shorthand property to be returned maybe? I would really appreciate it, thanks ahead of time.

I answered this question below, https://gist.github.com/austinksmith/10281815

Comment: If you want a consistent format, use `new Date().toISOString()`. That should provide the same output across all operating systems. Unfortunately, IE <= 8 don't support this.

Comment: It's dependent on locale settings, which are not necessarily standardized, especially for things like this. You can use the `.getTimezoneOffset()` API to get a numeric timezone offset, and then translate that through whatever mapping you like.

Comment: `java !== javascript`

Comment: I know java is not javascript, typo on my part what I meant was if there was a change in V8 to cause this

Comment: where all this strings can be used? only `Date.now()` is useful for me...

Comment: `new Date().getTimezoneOffset()/60` is timezone

Answer (score 2):

A few things:

- Yes, the output of `.toString()` on a JavaScript `Date` object is implementation dependent.  You will get different results on different operating systems, browsers, and versions.  This is defined by [ECMAScript 5.1 §15.9.5.2](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.5.2) as follows:

  > **15.9.5.2   Date.prototype.toString()**
  >
  > This function returns a String value. The contents of the String are implementation-dependent, but are intended to represent the Date in the current time zone in a convenient, human-readable form.
- Abbreviations like `EST` and `EDT` do not represent the entire time zone.  They represent specifically the *segment* of the time zone that applies to that particular moment in time.  remember, `new Date()` is initialized to the current "now".  See also "Time Zone != Offset" in [the timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).
- In general, time zone abbreviations are ambiguous.  EST might mean Eastern Standard Time in the US, or it might mean Eastern Standard Time in *Australia*.  Of course, they *might* use AEST in Australia, but who's to say that *they* are the ones to prepend an A instead of the Americans?  Besides, EST could also mean Australian Eastern *Summer* Time.  The abbreviation "CST" is even worse, having 5 different interpretations - two in Australia, one in the USA, one in China, and one in Cuba, and all have different offsets.  See [this list on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone_abbreviations) for more examples.
- The only standard for time zone abbreviations that are even defined in a specification are, those in [RFC822](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc822.txt) §5.1:

  ```
  zone        =  "UT"  / "GMT"                ; Universal Time
                                              ; North American : UT
              /  "EST" / "EDT"                ;  Eastern:  - 5/ - 4
              /  "CST" / "CDT"                ;  Central:  - 6/ - 5
              /  "MST" / "MDT"                ;  Mountain: - 7/ - 6
              /  "PST" / "PDT"                ;  Pacific:  - 8/ - 7
  ```

  But this is a very discouraged format, as it's focused just on the USA and says very little about the rest of the world.  The "military" zones A-Y were deprecated in [RFC1123](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1123.txt) anyway.  Only "Z" to represent UTC remains in modern formats like [ISO8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).
- You've said what you want, but not *why* you want it.  If you're just trying to determine the time zone of the user, please consider [jsTimeZoneDetect](http://pellepim.bitbucket.org/jstz/) which will return you an IANA time zone identifier, such as `America/New_York`.  You can then take that back to your server.  Most platforms have either native support or libraries for working with these.

You can use [`Date#toISOString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString) to get a consistent format.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't make sense, because javascript.

However, you can get the timezone offset by this way:

```
yourDate.getTimezoneOffset();
```

This will return the browser clients offset in minutes.
See [getTimezoneOffset()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_gettimezoneoffset.asp)

Answer (score 1):

Never tried but the text you are trying to find is, at the end of the day, a human-readable description of the timezone.  One could reasonably expect it to change based on language for example. It is entirely possible that different browsers have taken different approaches.

The part to program against, IMO, would be the GMT-0400.  Although a better way to get that in my opinion is

```
new Date().getTimezoneOffset() / -60
```

I suppose you could then translate that to a text yourself (either load an array of all timezones or via a web service) if it is important to have the same on all browsers.

**Edit in response to comments**

If you want to use the information programatically then I'd suggest using the offset instead.  If you want to present it to the user then you have a couple of options as I see it:

1. Use the Regexp you originally had and accept that it will be a
   slightly different text on different browsers/operating systems
2. Create a translation table of the  value returned from the regexp
   for the most popular browsers/OSes and present that (with the "key"
   beng the value returned by your regexp above).  In the event that no match
   exists you could either present the value returned by the regexp or
   fall back to a default translation per offset.
3. Combine the offset and some form of geoIP lookup to take a best
   guess at the zone (matching again to a list of your own for the text
   to present), maybe again with a default per offset.

Or, of course, some combination of the above.  What is the use case?  Why is a human readable but cross-browser text important?

Comment: Chose as best answer for providing a short easy way to calculate the offset which could then be matched up to a shorthand version of the timezone, wish this was something standardized across operating systems especially amongst the same browser but we can't win them all can we, thanks.

Comment: Deselected as best answer, using the offset isn't a reliable way to determine user timezone as several timezones share the same offset

http://www.timeanddate.com/library/abbreviations/timezones/na/

Not sure what a solution would be without using a library but it appears basing entirely on offset would be unreliable as well.

Comment: @user3512616 What exactly is it you need the timezone for? Would the offset not be sufficient.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist as explained in my comment, offset is not applicable since several timezones share the same offset, trying to programmatically check what timezone to use based on the offset value would be problematic and not be a full practical solution, I provided the best solution I could come up with in my answer, take a look at the approach i took, it encompasses all north american timezones and doesn't rely on offset for matching.

Comment: I accept (and suspect that @AnthonyGrist does too) that offset alone is not sufficient to determine time zone.  The question was why do you need the time zone as opposed to the offset?

Comment: @Adam I'm not sure I understand why the reasons behind I want something would matter, my question was specific in my needs and why i have that need is for all intents and purposes irrelevant. I appreciate the help I do just don't get so caught up in the "whys" just stay focused on the "hows" :)

Comment: What can be a reliable way to have my date printed, a way that doesn't depend on the OS and browser? Maybe date-fns has anything?

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate all the answers that were presented and here is what I came up with

```
getUserTz: function() {
    var tz;
    try {
      tz = new RegExp('\\(.*\\)').exec(new Date().toString())[0];
    } catch(e) { // IE10 and lower support
      tz = new Date().toString();
      tz = tz.replace(/[^A-Z]/g, '');
      var zones = ['ADT','AKDT','AKST','AST','CDT','EDT','EGST','EGT','EST','HADT','HAST','MDT','MST','NDT','PDT','PMDT','PMST','PST','WGST','WGT'];
      for(var i=0; i < zones.length; i++) {
        if(tz.indexOf(zones[i]) != -1) {
          tz = "(" + tz.substr(tz.indexOf(zones[i]), tz.length) + ")";
        }
      }
    }
    if(tz && tz.length <= 6) {
      return tz;
    }
    tz = tz.replace("US","");
    tz = tz.replace(/[^A-Z]/g, '');
    return "("+tz+")";
}
```

First try the original method I was using so that way I get for example (EDT) on mac, then if the characters returned are greater than 6 i take the string returned on windows for example

"(US Eastern Daylight Time)"

and strip out US, then i strip out all lowercase characters leaving me with "EDT" and wala, i have a shorthand property of this timezone, this probably doesn't cover all possible zones but my only concern at the moment is north american timezones and this should handle 90% of the use cases.

If anyone wants to use this code, feel free https://gist.github.com/austinksmith/10281815 I made some updates to support IE10 and lower since the returned format differs from IE11 , feel free to update to add support for other timezones :)

EDIT: This has been tested in IE11-9, FireFox, Chrome, Safari and works cross platform at least in regards to Windows & Mac PC's

Answer (score -1):

It is implementation dependent, meaning it is operating system and browser dependent, making it not very reliable if you want a consistent result.

If you want to parse it consistently in a specific way your best bet is gonna be to parse it out manually in code or to use a package like [datejs](http://www.datejs.com/) or similar.